# Supervisor start/stop/restart not behaving as expected

Tags: supervisord, celery

I am using supervisor to manage celery and due to occasional project requirements am required to add environment variables.  I set these in the supervisor [environment] section of the .conf file but simply using

```
service supervisor stop
service supervisor start
```

or

```
service supervisor restart
```

Does not seem to have the desired effect, I get errors that my program does not "know" what the newly added environment variables are.  In order to get the desired outcome I am having to find the supervisor PID and then send a kill signal, then start supervisor from the command line as shown above.

Am I just misunderstanding these commands or is there something I am missing in my supervisor .conf that needs to be set so that it will completely stop and restart?

Comment: Its not an answer to why the service command is not killing the process but perhaps you can get around the issue with 'supervisorctl reload'

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will look into it.  I was just wondering if this was the expected behavior (not killing) or some other error, bug or user.